# std::vector of type struct to NSMutableArray

Tags: c++, objective-c, vector, struct, nsmutablearray

I have been searching for hours but didn't get an answer, and I don't understand how to fix this.

I have a struct.

```
struct vertex {
    double x, y, z, r, g, b;
};
```

And a vector

```
std::vector<vertex> vecOfVertex;
```

How could I make a NSMutableArray? I probably have to iterate over the vector to populate the array.

```
id vecOfVertex = [NSMutableArray new];
for (auto points : vecOfVertex){

    [vecOfVertex addObject:points];
}
```

But `addObject` dosent take a struct.

Comment: True, NS(Mutable)Array can only hold Obj-C objects. You could wrap your struct in NSValue, or a custom wrapper object.

Comment: @jtbandes Thanks, I wrapped it into NSValue, that worked for me. Later I realised that I have full control of the Data Types and used NSArray instead of std::vector.